# How to horizontally center selected div based on it's new position?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div holding all 12 months, in a click-able button style.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, every month that I select, whether I clicked a month ahead or before to the current selected month, that month div should be moved to be horizontally centered, and the parent container has overflow-x set to auto, so the parent should scroll the button into view.

Except, all I know is that I need to get the month (div I just selected) offsets position and that I have to change the parent div's scroll position based on the child, that's what I have to go on.

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1u54yra/) of the exact problem I'm trying to solve.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    months: ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'],
    selected_month: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    select_month(event, key){
      this.selected_month = key;
      
      console.log(event);
      
      // parent - month-tracker__choice
   var parent = event.target.parentElement;
      
      // selected div
      var child = event.target;
      
      parent.scrollLeft = parent.scrollWidth - child.offsetWidth;
      //parent.scrollRight = parent.scrollWidth + child.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

body {
  width: 400px;
}

.month-tracker__month-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 62px;
}

.month-tracker__month-choice {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 74px;
}

.month-tracker__month-picker:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.month-tracker__month-picker:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.month-tracker__month-picker {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #858585;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 20px;
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 160px;
  height: 21px;
}

.month-tracker__month-selected {
  background-color: #3e76ff;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 14px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="month-tracker__month-container">
    <div class="month-tracker__month-choice">
      <div v-for="month, key in months" v-text="month" @click="select_month($event, key)" :class="{ 'month-tracker__month-selected': selected_month == key }" class="month-tracker__month-picker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the

```
parent.scrollLeft = parent.scrollWidth - child.offsetWidth;
```

with

```
parent.scrollLeft = child.offsetWidth * key;
```

The scrollLeft starts from left end. What the existing code is doing is setting it from right.

*Update:*

```
parent.scrollLeft = (child.offsetWidth + 40) * key - 70;
```

This is more accurate for the jsfiddle provided. Here 40 is the total margin provided on css. 70 is half the width of the month picker minus half the total padding

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
parent.scrollLeft = child.offsetLeft - (child.offsetWidth / 2);
```

Working demo below :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    months: ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'],
    selected_month: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    select_month(event, key){
      this.selected_month = key;
      
     // console.log(event);
      
      // parent - month-tracker__choice
   var parent = event.target.parentElement;
      
      // selected div
      var child = event.target;
      
      /**** this is what you need ****/
      parent.scrollLeft = child.offsetLeft - (child.offsetWidth/2);
      
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

body {
  width: 400px;
}

.month-tracker__month-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 62px;
}

.month-tracker__month-choice {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 74px;
}

.month-tracker__month-picker:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.month-tracker__month-picker:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.month-tracker__month-picker {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #858585;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 20px;
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 160px;
  height: 21px;
}

.month-tracker__month-selected {
  background-color: #3e76ff;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 14px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="month-tracker__month-container">
    <div class="month-tracker__month-choice">
      <div v-for="month, key in months" v-text="month" @click="select_month($event, key)" :class="{ 'month-tracker__month-selected': selected_month == key }" class="month-tracker__month-picker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```